# Subsonic REST 404 error

Tags: subsonic, rest

I'm trying to use the REST interface with Subsonic, but am not having any luck.

I have this in the web.config

```
<httpHandlers>
      <add type="SubSonic.WebUtility.RESTHandler, Subsonic" path=".xml" verb="*"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

and just to test that I have a version of Subsonic that has this functionality, this works fine (doesn't do anything but I get the Intellisense and it compiles fine):

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim dr As New SubSonic.WebUtility.RESTHandler

End Sub
```

But when I try a URL like http://localhost:59271/CBVA35/schedule/list.xml, I get a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to route "xml" to the rest handler:

```
<httpHandlers>
<add verb="*" path="*.xml" type="SubSonic.WebUtility.RESTHandler, Subsonic"/>
```

http://subsonicproject.com/tips-and-tricks/webcast-using-subsonic-s-rest-handler/

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem -- it worked fine using the ASP.NET dev web server but did not work in IIS. In addition to what Rob mentioned, I had to configure IIS mappings to accept other file types. See the comments here for details:

http://www.swindelles.com/ed/2008/07/22/creating-rest-web-services-in-c-sharp-2/